# How install JavaFX SDK on Ubuntu

Tags: openjdk, javafx

I to try to install **JavaFX SDK** as [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-May/021819.html) to say, with these command,

```
java --module-path /home/ss/openjfx-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin-sdk/lib/javafx-sdk-11.0.2
```

and to come,

[Output from javafx installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XKEn.png)

But when write,

```
sudo apt install openjfx openjfx-source
```

to come theme Screenshot,
[display installation from javafx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAK4S.png)

it to say that my **openjfx** is the anew..

With `java --version` to come,

> openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)

With `dpkg -l openjdk*` to come,

> Gewünscht=Unbekannt/Installieren/R=Entfernen/P=Vollständig Löschen/Halten
>   | Status=Nicht/Installiert/Config/U=Entpackt/halb konFiguriert/
>            Halb installiert/Trigger erWartet/Trigger anhängig
>   |/ Fehler?=(kein)/R=Neuinstallation notwendig (Status, Fehler: GROSS=schlecht)
>   ||/ Name                Version        Architektur    Beschreibung
>   +++-===================-==============-==============-===========================================
>   un  openjdk-11-jdk-head                 (keine Beschreibung vorhanden)
>   ii  openjdk-11-jre:amd6 11.0.4+11-1ubu amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
>   ii  openjdk-11-jre-head 11.0.4+11-1ubu amd64          OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT

It is my First Time that I doing it..., can Please anyone explains with easy words how to install it, Very Thanks!